# Keyboard Lag on ultrawide monitor (2560 x 1080)

Tags: keyboard, display

I'm using an LG 25UM58-P ultrawide monitor (2560x1080 @ 60hz), connected via mini display port to my MBP (Early 2015, Intel Iris Graphics 6100). I've used this setup for a few months without issue. But recently I've noticed significant keyboard lag, as well occasional performance lag / mouse lag. The lag tends to fluctuate.

I'm never doing anything too resource intensive, primarily basic web design / graphic design. I'm just not quite sure how to begin diagnosing this issue.. but would appreciate any insight!

**EDIT**
Pretty obvious detail I missed, obviously the lag disappears when I disconnect the monitor, and doesn't occur on the native MBP display.

Comment: Does the lag occur with the external monitor disconnected?

Comment: See edit, no it does not!

Comment: I'd test the connection cables/adaptors first. What specific MDP > HDMI brand and model adapter do you use to connect to the LG 25UM58-P? Do you have a spare HDMI cable you can swap in? After a few years of use in many classrooms where I work, we've come to rely on the [Belkin MDP > HDMI 4K adaptor](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-DisplayPort-Adapter-Compatible-Black/dp/B013P0JTX0). They're very sturdy and well designed.